# Bash set no memory for an executable

Tags: c, bash

So I am writing a tester in bash for my C program. One of the test cases should be whether the program correctly outputs "Error! program ran out of memory" under a certain `malloc` out of memory allocation condition.
Here is what I am trying to do in bash

```
echo =======TEST 10=========
echo Veryfing program output for out of memory.
(set memory allocation for executable 0) [<- pseudocode here]
output=`./executable input.csv output.csv`
if [[ "$output" != "Error! program ran out of memory" ]]; then 
      (...)
fi
```

The specific memory allocation fail condition in the C program is

```
struct Record *temp = (struct Record *) malloc(sizeof(struct Record));
if(temp == NULL){
     printf("Error! program ran out of memory");
     return(1);
}
```

I have searched online thoroughly how to achieve that but I can't seem to find a syntax for this. Does anyone have any hint on how I could set a specific memory allocation for an executable under a bash script?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `ulimit` ? Also you might hit something called *memory overcommitment*, so your `malloc` never fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output=`ulimit -v <limit> > /dev/null; ./executable input.csv output.csv`
```

Note that if the limit is too small, the shell may not be able to execute the program.

Here's a demo of how it works.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    if (malloc(10000000) == NULL)
        printf("oom\n");
    else
        printf("ok\n");
}
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
T=`./m`
U=`ulimit -v 10000 > /dev/null ; ./m`
echo T=${T}
echo U=${U}
```

Output:

```
T=ok
U=oom
```

Comment: I wonder if `ulimit` is also limiting the size that can be overcommited? Looking at your demo it looks like it is.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This sets a virtual memory limit for the process. This has advantages and disadvantages. One quirk is that a large read-only memory mapping of a file could fail because that uses virtual memory.